# ActiveRecord::AssociationTypeMismatch: User expected, got Fixnum

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I don't understand why I get the following error:

```
ActiveRecord::AssociationTypeMismatch: User(#29943560) expected, got Fixnum
```

when I do that in rails console: `@game = Game.create(:player => 1060, :played => 1061)`

I just want to create a new `Game` regarding model associations below.

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :game_as_player, :class_name => 'Game', :foreign_key => 'player_id'
    has_many :game_as_played, :class_name => 'Game', :foreign_key => 'played_id'
end

class Game < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :player, :class_name => 'User'
    belongs_to :played, :class_name => 'User'

    attr_accessible :player, :played, :score, :details, :viewed, :read
end
```

If anyone has an idea...
Thanks a lot!

Comment: According to your association, payer and played represent the same user(user_id). I don't think you should be setting different ids for player and played.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

It just says that it want a User and you give a Fixnum

You should do something like

```
@game = Game.create(:player => Player.find(1060), :played => Player.find(1061))
```

Or, if you want to give the users by ids

```
@game = Game.create(:player_id => 1060, :played_id => 1061)
```