# Rake db:seed not going through

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database, rake, seeding

I am running the command

```
rake db:seed
```

after I reset the database.  I am getting the error

```
User(#70157849141260) expected, got Fixnum(#70157833845020)
```

When I run

```
rake db:seed --trace
```

this is the feedback I get

```
** Invoke db:seed (first_time)
** Execute db:seed
** Invoke db:abort_if_pending_migrations (first_time)
** Invoke environment (first_time)
** Execute environment
** Invoke db:load_config (first_time)
** Execute db:load_config
** Invoke db:migrate (first_time)
** Invoke environment 
** Invoke db:load_config 
** Execute db:migrate
** Invoke db:_dump (first_time)
** Execute db:_dump
** Invoke db:structure:dump (first_time)
** Invoke environment 
** Invoke db:load_config 
** Execute db:structure:dump
Nothing annotated.
** Execute db:abort_if_pending_migrations
rake aborted!
User(#70157849141260) expected, got Fixnum(#70157833845020)
```

What could be my issue here?

Here is the code to create the user in the seed file:

```
User.create([
{ :email => "brooks.stevena@gmail.com", :username => "admin",
  :crypted_password => "$2a$10$zhjpf.6hg5w9DlI68GQsM.qSiQi33BgDaHtrCopV4Zn2nOeA2OnN6", :salt => "pqXxLgsnbB1CZzEcEFwF",
  :roles_mask => 1, :last_login_at => "2013-12-22 17:11:57", :last_logout_at => nil,
  :last_activity_at => "2013-12-24 15:31:46", :activation_state => "active",
  :activation_token => nil, :activation_token_expires_at => nil, :reset_password_token => nil,
  :reset_password_token_expires_at => nil, :reset_password_email_sent_at => nil, :remember_me_token => nil,
  :remember_me_token_expires_at => nil, :created_at => "2013-12-11 18:08:03", :updated_at => "2013-12-11 18:08:11",
  :ip => nil, :location => "1", :latitude => nil, :longitude => nil, :redmine_user => nil }
], :without_protection => true )
```

Comment: We'd need to see the contents of db/seeds.rb for starters...

Comment: All I did was a rake db:seed:dump so it loaded the seeds file with everything that was in the current db, then I reset it.

Comment: Absolutely similar question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17345024/activerecordassociationtypemismatch-user-expected-got-fixnum

Comment: Please see the edit to the above question, not able to find issue still.

Comment: `crypted_password` is this `encrypted_password` ?

Comment: array.each { |attributes| User.create(attributes, :without_protections => true) } ?

Answer (score 0):

You're parenthesis and brackets look incorrect.  I don't see why you need '[]' or '{}'.  I'd suggest changing your code to:

```
User.create(:email => "brooks.stevena@gmail.com", :username => "admin",
 :crypted_password => "$2a$10$zhjpf.6hg5w9DlI68GQsM.qSiQi33BgDaHtrCopV4Zn2nOeA2OnN6",
 :salt => "pqXxLgsnbB1CZzEcEFwF", :roles_mask => 1, 
 :last_login_at => "2013-12-22 17:11:57", :last_logout_at => nil,
 :last_activity_at => "2013-12-24 15:31:46", :activation_state => "active",
 :activation_token => nil, :activation_token_expires_at => nil, 
 :reset_password_token => nil, :reset_password_token_expires_at => nil,      
 :reset_password_email_sent_at => nil, :remember_me_token => nil,
 :remember_me_token_expires_at => nil, :created_at => "2013-12-11 18:08:03",
 :updated_at => "2013-12-11 18:08:11", :ip => nil, :location => "1", 
 :latitude => nil, :longitude => nil, :redmine_user => nil, 
 :without_protection => true )
```