# Type mismatch when seeding database

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, seeding

I'm trying to seed an application database, but I'm getting the following error:

```
ActiveRecord::AssociationTypeMismatch: Role(#97332160) expected,
got Fixnum(#76482890)
```

Here is the part of my `schema.rb` concerning the two table related to the problem:

```
create_table "roles", force: :cascade do |t|
  t.string   "role",       limit: 50, null: false
  t.datetime "created_at",            null: false
  t.datetime "updated_at",            null: false
end

create_table "users", force: :cascade do |t|
  t.string   "first_name", limit: 100, null: false
  t.string   "surname",    limit: 100, null: false
  t.string   "email",      limit: 255
  t.integer  "role_id",    limit: 11
  t.string   "password",   limit: 150
  t.datetime "created_at",             null: false
  t.datetime "updated_at",             null: false
end

add_index "users", ["first_name"], name: "index_users_on_first_name", using: :btree
add_index "users", ["role_id"], name: "index_users_on_role_id", using: :btree
add_index "users", ["surname"], name: "index_users_on_surname", using: :btree

add_foreign_key "users", "roles"
```

And here are my `seeds.rb` commands:

```
rl = Role.create(role: "root")
User.create(first_name: "Edvaldo", surname: "Silva de Almeida Júnior", email: "edvaldo@my.domain.com", role_id: rl.id, password: "my_password")

rl = Role.create(role: "admin")
User.create(first_name: "Daiely", surname: "Fanchin", email: "daiely@my.domain.com", role_id: rl.id, password: "other_password")

rl = Role.create(role: "user")
User.create(first_name: "César", surname: "Silva", email: "cesar@my.domain.com", role_id: rl.id, password: "yet_other_password")
```

I found [a question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17345024/activerecordassociationtypemismatch-user-expected-got-fixnum) where the accepted answer suggested I should do something like:

```
rl = Role.create(role: "root")
User.create(first_name: "Edvaldo", surname: "Silva de Almeida Júnior", email: "edvaldo@my.domain.com", role_id: Role.find(rl.id), password: "my_password")
```

I tried that, but got the same error! Besides, I'm using the `role_id` as association, not the role itself. So, as far as I'm concerned, it should receive a `Fixnum`, not a `Role`.

Comment: Thanks for your kind corections, @Drenmi.

Comment: rather than `role_id: Role.find(rl.id)` can you try `role: r1`

Comment: Please post the associations `add_foreign_key "users", "roles"` this will add `role_id` no required to seperately write `t.integer  "role_id",    limit: 11`

Comment: Tried that, @Rots, but now I get ActiveRecord::UnknownAttributeError: unknown attribute 'role' for User.

Comment: You mean the models, @RajarshiDas?

Comment: You might need a relationship in the Model, eg a User `belongs_to` a `Role`. http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html

Comment: In fact, @Rots, I have a **has_one :role** association in my User model. And when I went there to check this out I found my problem. I'm going to post it as an answer for future references.

Comment: @EdvaldoAlmeidaJr. Good. Look forward to seeing your answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had added a method **set_default_role** to my User model.

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :role
  after_initialize :set_default_role, :if => :new_record?

  def set_default_role
    if User.count == 0
      self.role ||= 1
    else
      self.role ||= 2
    end
  end

end
```

But this method was **wrong** and as soon as I rewrote it as

```
def set_default_role
  if User.count == 0
    self.role_id ||= 1
  else
    self.role_id ||= 2
  end
end
```

my seeding worked fine.

So, the problem was the fact I was tryind (inside this method) to set a Role to a Fixnum.

This serves as an **advice** to Rails newbies: **Seeding is not just forcing something to your database. It is a full evaluation of your model and sometimes an error may be caused by the execution of some method, not just by the values you try to load.**

Comment: There might be another lesson here. Did the stack trace tell you which line of code and which file the error happened in? In that case, the lesson is how to interpret an error log/message correctly.

Comment: Yeah! Really a newbie mistake here. And I did it! LOL

Answer (score 1):

`add_foreign_key "users", "roles"` this will add `role_id` column to users no required to separately write `t.integer "role_id", limit: 11`

there should be some associations

```
  class User < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :role
  end
```

and

```
create_table "users", force: :cascade do |t|
  t.string   "first_name", limit: 100, null: false
  t.string   "surname",    limit: 100, null: false
  t.string   "email",      limit: 255
  t.reference "role",      index: true
  t.string   "password",   limit: 150
  t.datetime "created_at",             null: false
  t.datetime "updated_at",             null: false
end


add_foreign_key "users", "roles", column: :role_id
```

hope it might solve it.

Comment: This has been done already. The associations are ok. When I went to check my User model I discovered the real problem, which I'm going to post as an answer for future references. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

The problem you have is simple:

```
role_id: Role.find(rl.id)
```

---

[`.find()`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/FinderMethods.html#method-i-find) returns a `Role` object.

Your `create` method is expecting a [`foreign_key`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Foreign_key) (integer) (`role_id: [int]`).

The simple fix would be:

```
 User.create(... role_id: Role.find(rl.id).id ...)
```

.. or ...

```
     User.create(... role_id: rl.id ...)
```

... or even better ...

```
 User.create(... role: rl ...)
```

--

## Fix

The real fix would *either* to set a `default` in your database, or manually set the `role_id`, as you have in your submitted answer.

I would strong recommend using the database `default` because then it doesn't matter what happens in your app - your database will always "default" to the role you set:

```
$ rails g migration SetDefaultForRole

$ db/migrate/set_default_for_role_____.rb
class SetDefaultForRole < ActiveRecord::Migration
   def change
      change_column :users, :role_id, :integer, default: 0
   end
end

$ rake db:migrate
```

The downside to this would be that this integer default would be set (unless you changed your db again). Whilst not a problem in itself, it would create an [antipattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anti-pattern) for your `Role` model (IE you can create any role, as long as it's *after* the initial one you made).

--

The other way would be to set the `Role` for the user.

You have this already; you could clean it up:

```
#app/models/user.rb
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
   before_create :set_role, if: Proc.new { |m| m.role_id.blank? }

   private

   def set_role
     self.role_id = "1" if User.count == 0
   end
end
```

Comment: Sorry, but Role.find(rl.id).id makes no sense at all. If I already have rl.id to search for, why would I search just to find the corresponding role and then pick the id, which I already have in r.id?

Comment: It's your code. I'm just explaining how you'd resolve it. After all, you were the one who used `Role.find(rl.id)`.......

Comment: Yeah. I got this part. I'm just asking what would be the advantage in doing this. Searching for a role knowing its id just to pick this id again. Maybe I missed something, but it seems to me I'd be running in circles doing this. But thanks anyway.

Comment: There is no advantage at all. I was just saying that you can't populate `role_id` with an object, it has to be an integer value. You'd get that integer *either* from `Role.find(x).id` or `rl.id`.

Comment: You wouldn't be running in circles, I was explaining what you got wrong, and the simple way to fix it. Your pattern is a different matter entirely

Comment: But if you read my questio again, you'll see I wasn't trying to pupulare role_id with a Role. I originally wrote role_id: rl.id, which stands for the same you wrote. Some people suggested me to do role_id: Role.find(rl.id), but it of course does not work.

Comment: I wrote my .02, if you don't like it, I'll take it down.

Comment: Not a question of like it or not. I already upvoted it for your good will. But it does not solve my problem, I'm sorry.

Comment: Thanks for the upvote :) Wish you well for the new year Feliz Anos!

Comment: Thanks! Same to you and your family, my friend.